# Treating gingivitis

Tags: dentistry, gums

If you brush your teeth twice a day, and floss once a day (in the evening).
Then your dentist tells you that you have gingivitis, because of bleeding gums. Why?
The only thing I can think of is if you do not brush your teeth thoroughly enough (or long enough maybe)?
Any suggestions? Is it possible to get gingivitis if you brush and floss every day? And what are some ways to avoid or improve it?

Comment: Hi! So your asking how you can get gingivitis if you brush everyday?

Comment: Yes, and also what I can improve.

Comment: Thank you for your post and welcome to Health SE! Your post is asking for personal medical advice so I am going to edit to try and mediate that. Questions asking this are not allowed on this site, because we can not answer those properly over the internet. If you dislike the edits feel free to rollback or re-edit. Sorry for the late edit, I didn't realize how personalized it was until it got nominated for closing because of this. Thank You!

Comment: My answer here, http://health.stackexchange.com/a/4141/2344, may address the technical aspect of Your question, more accurately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/gingivitis-gum-11), not having proper brushing techniques can result in gingivitis.

> Ask your dentist about the proper way to brush -- bearing down too
>   hard or missing spots can lead to gingivitis.

So not brushing thoroughly enough is a option to Gingivitis may develop in a person who brushes and flosses enough times a day.

[NIH](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/001056.htm)

> Gingivitis is due to the long-term effects of plaque deposits on your
>   teeth. Plaque is a sticky material made of bacteria, mucus, and food
>   debris that builds up on the exposed parts of the teeth. It is also a
>   major cause of tooth decay.

So even though you brush twice a day and floss you may still be leaving plaque behind.

[Gingivitis Prevention](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/gingivitis-gum-11?page=2)

- Brush your teeth twice a day and throw out old tooth brushes every 3 months.
- Make sure you visit a dentist at least every 6 months and consult them about your concerns and questions.
- Utilize floss and mouthwash. Consult you dentist on which types are better for you and how to floss properly so that you do not damage your mouth.

[9 Toothbrushing Mistakes -- and How to Fix Them](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/features/brushing-teeth-mistakes)

- Make sure your toothbrush fits in your mouth and is not to big or to small.
- Don't brush to many times a day, over 3 times is probably to much.
- A good session should last around 2 minutes. Take your time and don't rush.
- Wait a  hour after you eat to brush teeth because acid from food weakens enamel, and don't store your toothbrush in the bathroom.

It is important to consult your dentist on what is best, as gingivitis is a early stage of gum disease. So prevention and treatment is important in this stage. Treatment can be usually just better dental hygiene, but consulting a dentist would be best.

Comment: Did you mean brush directly after eating?

Comment: @user8669 No, I'll clarify. Brushing after eating causes tooth break down.