# Should I wash dental floss pick before passing on the next teeth?

Tags: dentistry, hygiene, gums, floss-flossing, dental-floss-pick

Very simple question, which I checked [is not answered here.](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/874/how-do-i-know-if-im-flossing-correctly), so please, don't link that question.

I'm using a dental floss pick[like this one](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=dental%20floss%20pick&espv=2&biw=1517&bih=708&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB3IqGhbvRAhUHgJAKHaLGCcUQ_AUICCgB), [or this one](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=dental%20floss%20pick&espv=2&biw=1517&bih=708&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB3IqGhbvRAhUHgJAKHaLGCcUQ_AUICCgB#imgrc=cDBtaCmCw9n2AM%3A). I use it normally, passing in between teeth and following normal guidelines. However, after passing it between two teeth, yellow residue of food and other things gets in the floss, should I wash it or remove it with my fingers before re-passing it over other teeth?

Answer (score 2):

The correct use of dental floss is to use a new portion of the floss for every site. The easiest way to achieve it is through the loop or circle technique, using a new part of the loop every time.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L5Q5ObxFYY)

Also, always use the floss before the toothbrush. If you use after, you will remove toothpaste (fluoride) deposited in the surface of the teeth.

Comment: If you don't remove plaque between the teeth before using the toothbrush, the toothpaste and fluoride won't even diffuse properly between the teeth.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the share. As per the article, fluoride can be stored in biological fluide or the enamel. I was thinking more in the sense that if we start using fluoride today (not having used it before) it would take time to diffuse through the plaque and tartar to reach the enamel on the surfaces between teeth. Likewise, it would take time to build up the reservoir in preexisting plaque, as opposed to removing it all, and if new plaque builds up, it will more readily accumulate fluoride as it's being built up.